# Static variables inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, static

```
public class Base{
        protected String str;

    public static final Base ERROR = new Base("error");
...
}

public class Derived extends Base{
        public static final Derived OTHER = new DERIVED("other");
        public Derived(String str) {
        super(str);
        }
    }

Derived page = Derived.OTHER; //OK
page = (Drived)Derived.ERROR; //ClassCastException
```

So can I cast static member variable from Base to Derived class?

Comment: it's a good practice when casting, to verify using instanceOf, if the cast would be suitable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't.

It is not possible to cast `Derived.ERROR` to `Derived` since **it's not an instance of `Derived`**. It's an instance of `Base`.

It may help clear up the confusion to realize that `Base.ERROR` and `Derived.ERROR` are two ways to refer to the same object.

Answer (score 4):

`Derived.ERROR` refers to exactly the same object as `Base.ERROR`, and that object is of class `Base`, so it cannot be cast to `Derived`.

Answer (score 1):

Parent can not be cast to Child. This can simply be understood by following example:

```
public class Parent
{
    public void parentMethod() { }
}


public class Child extends Parent
{
    public void childMethod() { }
}

   .....
Parent parent = new Parent();
```

So if we were able to cast `Parent` object to `Child`, which means we can call `childMethod()` on `parent` object, which is incorrect as the object `parent` is of type `Parent` which does not have `childMethod()` method.

I hope my explanation is not confusing.

Answer (score 0):

static variable are not bound to instance but to class

Answer (score 0):

No...You Can't do this..As you have to make it the instance of Derive Class..not the Base  Class